# MIN IF with multiple criteria Excel (Return earliest date if)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've used the (hacked) MAX IF function before, so I am not sure why my MIN IF here isn't working (and yes I am array-entering). Doubt that would be the issue, but I'm using Excel on a virtual box (Windows Excel on a Mac).

I determined that the formula was breaking in the IF function. As you can see, it is returning 0, or FALSE, so when I wrap it in the MIN formula it is just giving me an issue. The desired result here should be 6/11/2014.

[image: Example]

Comment: how your dates are stored? as text ot as dates? if as text, try this one: `=MIN(IF(C2:C5=G7,IF(D2:D5>0,DATEVALUE(B2:B5))))` with array entry

Comment: they are stored as values, so dates/numbers, not text

Comment: in that case `=MIN(IF(C2:C5=G7,IF(D2:D5>0,B2:B5)))` should work (I've just tested it with your data)

Comment: Let me try on a native Windows

Comment: try to select range `H2:H5`, _with selected range_ enter formula `=IF(C2:C5=G7,IF(D2:D5>0,B2:B5))` in formula bar and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. What output do you get?

Comment: FALSE, FALSE, 41801 (6/11/2014 - correct date), 41974. I don't understand why it wouldn't work on a different row level.

Comment: not sure why this function not working for you, but also try: `=MIN(IF(C2:C5=G7,IF(D2:D5>0,B2:B5,"")))` and `=MIN(IF(C2:C5=G7,IF(D2:D5>0,B2:B5,9E+307)))` both with array entry

Comment: The IF function you show in the question isn't "broken" - when you put that in a single cell like H7 - (not on a referenced row) you will just see the result from the first row - in this case because C2 <> "Teddy" you get FALSE and that's what you see in H7

Comment: Your formula works properly here, and wrapping it with MIN returns the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

Showing your formula working with your data:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this formula in H7:

```
=INDEX(B2:B5,MATCH(1,IF(C2:C5=G7,IF(D2:D5>0,1)),0))
```

confirm with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.